# Question on Overriding a method in Customization

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

What if I override a method on a particular screen.

`For example:` let's say Journal Transactions Screen, I've overridden the method `Release()`, I've made it to stop `Posting Transactions` on the `General Ledger` with that customization applied, when releasing a document on a screen that produces `Journal Transaction` *Documents* that also triggers auto-release, will the customization, the overriden method, will apply first?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, extensions are called first followed by base calls.
If you think the call order ambiguity might lead to errors with your specific code in the handler I'd recommend to explicitly declare and call the base method in the overridden method.

Using Acumatica customization project editor is the easiest way to get the declaration syntax down:
[image]

That way there's no doubt with the calling order:

```
public delegate IEnumerable ReleaseDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);

[PXOverride]
public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter, ReleaseDelegate baseMethod)
{
  // Put your code before calling base
  return baseMethod(adapter);

  /* Or after calling base

     IEnumerable returnValue = baseMethod(adapter);
     // put your code to be executed after base here

     return returnValue;
  */
}
```

Comment: actually, I tried my solution, it seems that when I customize the screen business logic, it applies to all.